# SQLite How to stack groups horizontally?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example, say I have a table (id is letter):

```
letter|color |number
a     |green |2
a     |blue  |3
b     |red   |3
b     |blue  |4
b     |yellow|1
c     |red   |9
c     |blue  |5
```

What I want is to transform it to:

```
letter|color_1|color_2|color_3|number_1|number_2|number_3
a     |green  |blue   |       |2       |3       |
b     |red    |blue   |yellow |3       |4       |1
c     |red    |blue   |       |9       |5       |
```

What type of SQL transformation is this? My boss said it is something done frequently but I've never seen it before? Also, how would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pivot query.  If you know that you want three sets of columns, then you can use conditional aggregation.

The problem in SQLite is that you don't have an easy way to enumerate things.  For this, you can use a subquery:

```
select t.letter,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then color end) as color_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then color end) as color_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then color end) as color_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then number end) as number_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then number end) as number_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then number end) as number_3
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.letter = t.letter and t2.color <= t.color) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by t.letter;
```

Comment: Thanks! What if we don't know the number of columns? I have a huge dataset(100gb+). Is there another sql language that is easier to enumerate those columns?

Comment: @BrianH.Truong . . . If you don't know the number of columns, you need to do a dynamic pivot.  In SQLite, it might just be easier to do the processing on the application side.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, what do you mean by application side?

Comment: @BrianH.Truong . . . Wherever you are calling the query from, such as PHP, java, C#, and so on.